# UIView inheritance and custom initializers throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS in swift

Tags: xcode, inheritance, uiview, initialization

I have classes with inheritance like:
UIView -> TestSubclass -> Test

class `Test` has some properties and methods. It works until I add some initializers into class `TestSubclass`:

```
class TestSubclass : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("CustomActivityInit")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("CustomActivityInitCoder")
    }
}
```

After this I can't access properties of my `Test` class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var test = Test(frame: CGRect.nullRect)
    test.test = "zzz"
}
```

and get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on line `test.test = "zzz"`

Could you help me understand the reason, please?

This is the test project to see the issue https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d8fvxm0es9b5n4/TestInit.zip

I use XCode 6 beta 5, deployment target iOS7+, iOS8 SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override `init()` because of inheritance from `UIView`.

```
class TestSubclass : UIView {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

The reference from Apple:

> ### Default Initializers
>
> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or base class that provides default values for all of its properties and does not provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default values.
> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: Thank you! It really works. But it is really wierd for me. I don't understand how it worked before. Why `TestSubclass` and it's properties works good without overriding init()? Only `Test` that inherits `TestSubclass` was buggy. When does init() method called if I work with init(frame:)? Why does xcode suggest only init(frame:) and init(coder aDecoder:) methods?

Comment: The fact, I can't tell how it works exactly by the Apple Documentation or even ebook. It's must relative with `Class Inheritance and Initialization` and `Initializer Chaining`. I guess the property won't be initialized because the `Test` class is not **base class** and the super class doesn't fulfill the rules of inheritance. Therefore, you can either override `init()` in `TestSubclass` or don't override any designated initializer in `TestSubclass`. These are the solutions may work as well so far as i know.